# How to store multiple entity instances in a single SQL table attribute

Tags: sql

I have these SQL tables

- `Date` (d_id, blabla, **products_1**, **products_2**)
- `Product_1` (p1_id)
- `Product_2` (p2_id)

and I want to save in a row of `Date`, a party of `Product_1` and a party of `Product_2`

The "easy" way would be the creation of 2 other tables

- `Date_P1` (d_id, p_id)
- `Date_P2` (d_id, p_id)

For example

```
Date_P1: {(d1,p01), (d1,p02), (d1,p04), (d2,p01), (d2,p03), (d3,p02)} etc.
```

but I don't think this is the best way I can do this...

Is this possible to save some kind of **array** as a "Date" attribute?

*(array containing product_1 ids and product_2 ids)*

Comment: well my first look at this is you have a table called date?  I would focus on fixing that issue first

Comment: the name is just for example.. :P in the real table I have to store much more than 4 attributes..

Comment: Saving an **array** is the first thing that you never want to do in SQL or any Relational DBMS.  That's why it's the First Rule of Data Normalization.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: if your attribute is indeed "natively" an array, then it does not violate the 1NF. Quote from C.J. Date' book "The Relational Database dictionary": "*every row and column intersection in that table contains exactly one value of the applicable type, nothing more and nothing less. (The value in question can be arbitrarily complex, it can even be a table*". But I agree that there are really very few cases where this is the case - and this is definitely not one of them

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I am aware of Date's latter-day revisionisms, Codd's orginal rules allowed no repeating fields and in his original presentation he explicitly used the term "array" as an example.  The only exception he ever made to this that I am aware of is if it were "opaque" to the DBMS.  (In other words a columns can contain anything as long as the DBMS doesn't know and cannot unpack it)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a many to one (or many to many) relationship in your database, then the best way to do this is indeed to have tables Date, Product1 and Date_P1.

Another idea would be to store a "list of product ids" in form of a string, for example `Date:{(d1, "p01;p02;p03") ...}`. The problem with this is that some queries might be hard to perform efficiently, and it is not at all recommended to use this

Comment: That other idea you mentioned is a bad one.

Comment: I know, I only mentionned it if he really needs a single table